# How to understand "fer cryin' out loud" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> “Sorry?" barked Hagrid, turning to stare at the Dursleys, who shrank back into the shadows. "It's them as should be sorry! I knew yeh weren't gettin' yer letters but I never thought yeh wouldn't even know abou' Hogwarts, **fer cryin' out loud**! Did yeh never wonder where yer parents learned it all?"

This is from Harry Potter. I think "**fer cryin' out loud**" is "**for crying out loud**", but I don't know how to relate it to the context. How should we understand it in the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"For crying out loud" indicates the speaker is surprised or irritated. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/for-crying-out-loud)'s definition is pretty clear:

> I am annoyed or surprised by this:
>   *Oh, for crying out loud, would you stop leaving your magazines all over the house!*

Similar idioms include: *for Christ's sake*, *for God's sake*, for Pete's sake, and so on and so forth.

So that person in your quoted text is saying:

> How did you not know about Hogwarts? How have you not heard about Hogwarts? This is where your parents received their training. Why hasn't anybody told you?

Comment: oh, so it's an idiom. I haven't found it in my dictionary at my first search. Thanks!